# Xamarin Native Views in XAML doesn't show on IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I tried to add a native view in a xamarin forms xaml file.
I have downloaded the example code from this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-views/xaml
Everything works file for Android and UWP. But for IOS, it can't display the native view, just a blank view.
I tried every example I can find on that page , turning out to the same result.
I'm using the latest version of VS 2017 and Xamarin.
Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried connecting your Windows with mac?

Comment: I have reported this issue at this [link](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2845).  Let's wait for response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by using Xamarin.forms 3.0.0, and a service release will be available for this soon.

Refer to [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2845).